# issue using $_GET and $_POST to echo something if a user has posted

Tags: php, post, get, undefined-index

I'm having an issue that's been driving me crazy for a while now because I just can't figure it out.

I want to echo something like "succeed" if the user creates a post from a form.

This is what i got so far in my db-querys file:

```
if ($_REQUEST) {
    $name           = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $price      = $_REQUEST['price'];
    $dateofevent    = $_REQUEST['dateofevent'];
    $time           = $_REQUEST['time'];
    $textinfo       = $_REQUEST['textinfo'];
    $leg            = $_REQUEST['leg'];

    $sql= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO events(name, dateofevent, time, price, leg, textinfo) 
    VALUE (:name, :dateofevent, :time, :price, :leg, :textinfo)");

    $sql->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $sql->bindParam(':dateofevent', $dateofevent);
    $sql->bindParam(':time', $time);
    $sql->bindParam(':price', $price);
    $sql->bindParam(':leg', $leg);
    $sql->bindParam(':textinfo', $textinfo);

    $sql->execute();

    $url = $_POST['name'];
    header('Location: events.php?'.$url);
}
```

Then I've tried using `$_GET` to echo out something if the url is correct.

This is the code in my view-file so far:

```
if(isset($_GET[$url])) {
    echo "success";
}
```

Here I get undefined variable $url and the echo doesn't work, nothing shows.

I've also tried something like:

```
$url = 'path/to/event.php';
if (!$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $_SERVER[$url]) {
    echo "success";
}
```

And here I get undefined index path/to/event.php and the echo doesn't work aswell, nothing shows.

Can anyone please help me with my problem? I'm new in php so can't get any further with this, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar');
$key   = 'foo';
echo $array[$key]; // outputs 'bar'
```

That's what you're trying to do there, which obviously doesn't work because `$url` is not a defined variable. In fact, since the name value doesn't have a *key* in the URL it's associated with, you can't get it that way from `$_GET` at all.

The simplest solution for you is to add a key in the URL:

```
header('Location: events.php?name=' . urlencode($_POST['name']));
                             ^^^^^
```

and get the value by key:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

It's odd though to use a user-entered name as is for a *primary id* to something in the database. You should rather use the autoincrementing numeric id of the record in the database.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the name thing as I was trying to get it to work, out of lazyness because it was easy just to take something I've allready wrote. I'll switch it to the id.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've solved it like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'path/to/events.php') {
}
else {
    echo 'success';
}
```